# Nvidia-390 is not installing on my ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

```
sudo apt install nvidia-390 nvidia-390-dev
```

Package 'nvidia-390' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

Package name is wrong.